# iOS TableView with header section and row with open and collapse

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How should I create a tableview controller with fixed header section and table cells should contain sub tableview and onn click of that sub table cells navigate to next screen. Sample source will help a lot.

Header 1

->Cell 1.1 //Collapsed

-Cell 1.2 //Open

```
subCell 1.2.1 //On click goto next screen

subCell 1.2.2 //On click goto next screen
```

->Cell 3 //Collapsed

Header 2

->Cell 2.1 //Collpased

-Cell 2.2 //Opened

```
subCell 2.2.1 //On click goto next screen

subCell 2.2.2 //On click goto next screen
```

->Cell 3 //Collpased

[image]

Comment: Why don't use another tableView with Header collapsed instead of collapsed cell? Each section has only one cell and this cell has another table with Collapsed Headers that expand if you touch

Comment: You are asking a number of questions. I'd suggest you simplify by working on one feature at a time and asking specific questions about it when you hit a problem. Providing the code you are using will help others to help you as well.

Comment: I have added image which shows tableview structure to simplify what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: @VishwanathDeshmukh this is called Multilevel-TableView http://me.deepakbhati.com/2016/03/23/multilevel-uitableview/

Comment: Thanks @ferbass, its very helpful and what I was looking for. Can we open all cells open for level 1?

Comment: @VishwanathDeshmukh yes check the DidSelectRowAtIndexPath, you can use insertRowsAtIndexPaths to make it all open on the first level, you just need small changes

Comment: Thanks a lot @ferbass..!